# Descriptive statistics of the data from nhanes 2003 -2004

Tags: r, database, missing-data

I am trying to reproduce the original results (n = 9643) of missing data percentage from table 5 of the article "[A robust imputation method for missing responses and covariates in sample selection models](https://raw.githack.com/maf335/stack/master/ogundimu2019.pdf)". I downloaded the nhanes data 2003-2004 and created a script to read them. I was able to faithfully reproduce the results of all variables except the income variable. I've read the article several times and researched a lot, but I can't see where I'm going wrong. Does anyone know how to find the 24.41% missing data value for the income variable? Below is my code!

```
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")
library("tidyverse")
library(Hmisc)
mydata <- sasxport.get("https://raw.githack.com/maf335/stack/master/DEMO_C.XPT")
attach(mydata)
newdata <- mydata %>% select(seqn,ridageyr, riagendr, dmdeduc, ridreth1, indhhinc)
names(newdata) <- c("id","age","gender", "educ", "race", "income")
attach(newdata)
##################
mydata2 <- sasxport.get("https://raw.githack.com/maf335/stack/master/BMX_C.XPT")
attach(mydata2)
newdata2 <- mydata2 %>% select(seqn,bmxbmi)
names(newdata2) <- c("id","bmi")
attach(newdata2)
##############
mydata3 <- sasxport.get("https://raw.githack.com/maf335/stack/master/BPX_C.XPT")
attach(mydata3)
newdata3 <- mydata3 %>% select(seqn, bpxsy1)
names(newdata3) <- c("id", "sbp")
attach(newdata3)
#################
dt <- merge(newdata, newdata2, by="id")
data <- merge(dt, newdata3, by= "id")
attach(data)
####################
perc <- function(x,data){
  nna <- ifelse(sum(is.na(x))!=0,summary(x)[[7]],"x has no missing data")
  perc <- ifelse(sum(is.na(x))!=0,(nna/length(data$id))*100,"x has no missing data")
  #perc <- (nna/length(data$id))*100
  return(perc)
}


perc(sbp,data)
perc(age,data)
perc(gender,data)
perc(bmi,data)
perc(educ,data)
perc(race,data)
perc(income,data)


hist(data$income, prob= TRUE, breaks = seq(1, 99, 0.5), xlim = c(1,10), ylim = c(0,0.35), main = "Histogram of Income", xlab = "Category")
```

The article "[Subsample ignorable likelihood for regression
analysis with missing data](https://raw.githack.com/maf335/stack/master/little2011.pdf)" also presents, in table 1, the income variable with high value of missing data. Even considering a smaller number of observations (n = 9041).

Comment: I really don't know...but interesting. My first thought is about 'refused' and 'don't know' being recoded as missing (which CDC will suggest), but that wouldn't explain such a discrepancy...interestingly, the SMMR article indicates 10 interval categories for income, which I don't think is correct (should be 11 if counting $75k+ right? https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/DEMO_C.htm#INDHHINC) if you include that last category and 'refused' and 'don't know' as missing you would get around 25% missing which is close...??? Let me know what you think-still doesn't explain other article.

Comment: @Ben You are right, with this change I got the correct values from the first article. I will do the same for the second. Thank you!